# C format specifier mismatch with data type

Tags: c, format, specifications

I would like to know, as per C specification, what is the expected behavior in C if the given data type does not match the format specifier expected. For eg:

```
    printf("%lu\n", 2);
```

Comment: The behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type will be promoted per the normal promotion rules (plus two exceptions) if possible. If the promotion is not possible, the behavior is undefined in C11 per [7.16.1.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> The va_arg macro expands to an expression that has the specified type
>   and the value of the next argument in the call. The parameter ap shall
>   have been initialized by the va_start or va_copy macro (without an
>   intervening invocation of the va_end macro for the same ap). Each
>   invocation of the va_arg macro modifies ap so that the values of
>   successive arguments are returned in turn. The parameter type shall be
>   a type name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object
>   that has the specified type can be obtained simply by postfixing a *
>   to type. If there is no actual next argument, **or if type is not
>   compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted
>   according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is
>   undefined, except for the following cases**:
>
> - one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in
>     both types;
> - one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

Comment: C89 is not standard C and outdated since 18 years now. Standard is C11, nothing else.

Comment: If you link to a draft (you cannot link to the final standard document), use the final draft (n1570), no intermediate document. Please be more cautious from the start next time.

Comment: The part about integer promotion is not the actual point. OP asks for the **given** type which is - in my understanding - the already promoted type. So the actual answer is simply: it is UB. That should be emphasised. But then, it is useless question without any research done by OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimSweet

Answer (score 2):

It is **undefined behavior**.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688449/c-format-specifier-mismatch-with-data-type#comment70573657_41688449)

`2` is an *decimal integer constant* with a value of 2 and type of `int`.

When `2` is passed to `...` part of `printf(const char * format, ...);` it undergoes *default argument promotions* , which in this case is `int` stays an `int`.  `printf()` receives the `2` as an `int`.

`"%ld"` expects to match a `long`.  As `long` and `int` are different types:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.    C11dr §7.21.6.1 9

Even if the size and range of `long` and `int` are the same, the result is still UB - although there is debate on this point.  On many platforms, the UB is acceptable.  In any case, this code should be avoided.

A well enabled compiler will warn of the mis-match.

Alternatives:

```
printf("%d\n", 2);
printf("%lu\n", 2ul);
printf("%lu\n", 2UL);
printf("%lu\n", 1ul * 2);
printf("%lu\n", (undersigned long) 2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @chux